# for loop and nested for loop

Tags: python

for line in file2.splitlines():
  for l in file1.splitlines():
    if line in l:
     print l

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Print the lines of each file?

Comment: Please give examples: what you get? what you want to get? Thanks

Comment: Can you please write in English what your desired output is?

Comment: Note that `"" in "hello"` is True, so a blank line in file1 will be "found" in every line in file2

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dictionary out of the lines in second file would be a faster solution and it will get rid of the duplicates too:

```
from collections import defaultdict

second_file = open('second.txt')
second_file_dict = defaultdict(int)
first_file_dict = defaultdict(int)

for line in second_file:
    second_file_dict[line.strip()] += 1
second_file.close()

first_file = open('first.txt')
for line in first_file:
    if line in second_file_dict and not in first_file_dict:
        print line
    first_file_dict[line.strip()] += 1        
first_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print list(set(file2.splitlines()) & set(file1.splitlines()))
```

Comment: `splitlines()` returns a list, the `&` operator isn't implemented for lists.  Did you mean to convert those to sets?

Comment: @F.J: yes ofcourse I did, but i forgot in the hurry :) That is why i casted the whole expression to `list`, which wouldn't made sense if I didn't think of sets.