# How can I get rid of repetition in the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

```
for line in file2.splitlines():
  for l in file1.splitlines():
    if line in l:
     print l
```

How can i get rid of the repetition?

Comment: Umm, did you just re-ask [the same question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752065/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-repetition-in-the-nested-for-loop)

Comment: why would you post it twice?

Comment: To be fair, it is very unlikely that a question with no upvotes that is 15 hours old will get any new answers.  However it would be nice if the first question had at least been deleted first.

Comment: Or it could be edited and improved to bring it back to the front of the list.  Your code probably doesn't do what you want; when you read the first line in the outer loop, the inner loop reads all the data in file2; the next time through the loop, the inner loop does nothing (there are no lines left to read).  You'll need to think again.

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate question, but l'm new in the forum and I have not experience in this before.I tried to delete the first one but it was difficult since it have answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wan to print duplicates.

You can do it like this:

```
print [line for line in file2.splitlines() if line in file1.splitlines()]
```

But if you want to do it in a better way, use sets:

```
print list(file2.splitlines() & file1.splitlines())
```

Comment: Wouldn't the first snippet call `file1.splitlines()` on each iteration of `line`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dictionary out of the lines in second file would be a faster solution and it will get rid of the duplicates too:

```
from collections import defaultdict

second_file = open('second.txt')
second_file_dict = defaultdict(int)
first_file_dict = defaultdict(int)

for line in second_file:
    second_file_dict[line.strip()] += 1
second_file.close()

first_file = open('first.txt')
for line in first_file:
    if line in second_file_dict and not in first_file_dict:
        print line
    first_file_dict[line.strip()] += 1        
first_file.close()
```

Comment: I tried this, but no result

Comment: @5555555555 Do you get an error?

Comment: not error, but no result

Comment: @5555555555 Hope you are opening the two files in question? Updated my answer to that effect.

Comment: It works only if I use the for loop in the second_file_dict, but this makes repetition